# CakeLog and scope : Restricting scope to only one logger

Tags: cakephp

I'd like to set a up log file so that only messages with a scope of soap get logged to that file.  Conversely, I'd also like to prevent messages with a scope of soap being logged against the default logs of debug and error.

Here is my current setup in bootstrap.php.

```
CakeLog::config('soap', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('info','debug','error'),
    'scopes' => array('soap'),
    'file' => 'soap'
));

CakeLog::config('debug', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('notice', 'info', 'debug'),
    'file' => 'debug',
));
CakeLog::config('error', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'),
    'file' => 'error',
));
```

Here is a snippet from one of my libs that makes soap calls.

```
        CakeLog::debug("REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n", 'soap');
        CakeLog::debug("RESPONSE:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n", 'soap');

    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        CakeLog::error(print_r($result,true), 'soap');
        CakeLog::error('Exception: (' . $e->getCode() . ') ' . $e->getMessage(), 'soap');
        if (isset($client)) {
            CakeLog::error("Errored REQUEST:\n" . print_r($client->__getLastRequest(), true) . "\n", 'soap');
        }
```

When I do this current set up, I get the debug soap messages in debug.log and soap.log, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [CakeLog::config documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-CakeLog.html#_config)

> If you don't define any scopes an adapter will catch all scopes that match the handled levels.

so, debug logger write all messages with type `'types' => array('notice', 'info', 'debug'),`

Now how you can avoid it?  Seems you have 2 ways:

- use CakeLog::write with custom error type

  CakeLog::write('soap', "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n");

in this case, according documentation of [CakeLog::write method](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-CakeLog.html#_write)

> integer|string $type
>      Type of message being written. When value is an integer or a string matching the recognized levels, then it will be treated log levels. Otherwise it's treated as scope.

scope and type will same and have 'soap' value, so, message will not logged in debug logger, but only in soap.

- leave it as now, cause save all debug messages in one file and some messages in some specific logs not such bad idea.

Comment: First technique doesn't work anymore in cakephp 3.  We have to store Log in two places !

Answer (score 1):

A logger with no defined scopes will log all scopes, as is the case with the debug and error log configuration in the question.

To prevent the debug+error logs from containing soap messages, you'll need to defined explicitly what scopes they should act upon:

```
CakeLog::config('debug', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('notice', 'info', 'debug'),
    // restrict to scope=type only
    'scopes' => array('notice', 'info', 'debug'),
    'file' => 'debug',
));
CakeLog::config('error', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'),
    // restrict to scope=type only
    'scopes' => array('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'),
    'file' => 'error',
));
```

Cake does have a logging [safety net](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Log/CakeLog.php#L457) so that if a log message has been filtered out completely (by what is effectively, bad config) it will at least be written to the default logger. So a call like this:

```
$this->log('special', 'foo');
```

*will* still be written to the foo log (with default config).

### A debug log without all messages isn't a debug log

As answered by Vadim - it's *not* a bad idea to have a debug log with all log messages in it. This permits grepping a single file for information, instead of needing to look in several different files when things aren't quite going to plan in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification how specifying scopes for the default debug and error. I guess I need to reevaluate my expectations of logging the soap messages. On one hand, I want to log the raw messages. On the other hand, I don't want my debug.log filling up with all this info. Maybe I need to find a Windows based solution for a log roller, so the debug.log stays at a reasonable size.

Comment: The solution doesn't work because the condition `(in_array($type, $scopes))`: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/e46745731939e50284c9b939440d084b8a206098/lib/Cake/Log/CakeLog.php#L434

Comment: @luissquall can you clarify what doesn't work please.

Comment: I couldn't prevent the error log from containing the X messages by adding scopes to the error log config. My case looks like this: https://gist.github.com/luissquall/bdcf6244b818ed6153df. I found that the aforementioned condition causes the log to be sent to the error log. Perhaps I'm missing something. Thank you @AD7six.

Comment: That's the mentioned safety net @luissquall. If logging is configured such that a message will go nowhere - CakePHP will write the message anyway to the default logger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CakeLog::disable('debug') and CakeLog::disable('error') to disable these two default log streams temporarily before CakeLog::write to 'soap'.

And don't forget to immediately restore by using CakeLog::enable('debug') and CakeLog::enable('error') after 'soap' log was written.

Sample:

```
CakeLog::debug('THIS MESSAGE WILL APPEAR IN debug.log and soap.log', 'soap');
CakeLog::disable('debug');
CakeLog::debug('THIS MESSAGE WILL NOT APPEAR IN debug.log but soap.log only', 'soap');
CakeLog::enable('debug');
CakeLog::debug('THIS MESSAGE WILL APPEAR IN debug.log and soap.log', 'soap');
```

[CakeLog::disable](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#CakeLog::disable)